# How to handle exceptions thrown in subscriptions to processors in Project Reactor

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

Consider the following test:

```
@Test
void test() {
    DirectProcessor<Object> objectTopicProcessor = DirectProcessor.create();

    Runnable r = mock(Runnable.class);

    objectTopicProcessor.subscribe(next -> {throw new RuntimeException("eee");});
    objectTopicProcessor.subscribe(next -> r.run());

    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> objectTopicProcessor.onNext("")); // exception is thrown

    verify(r).run(); // it's not run
}
```

Imagine that I build an API where I expose the processor to the client.
When someone has multiple subscriptions and one of them throws exception, the other calls are not executed. Furthermore, exception is propagated and thrown out from `objectTopicProcessor.onNext("")`. I'd like to prevent such behavior.

I know that client can wrap his code in try-catch inside subscription, but is there any other way? Sometimes, for example, NullPointer may happen or client can forget about checking the exception. For the API it's also inconvenient to force clients to try-catch all exceptions.

What are the best strategies to handle such cases?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the code passed to the `subscribe` method is by default executed on the main thread. It first encounters the exception and fails immediately without executing the second `subscribe` block.
In order to achieve parallelism, use `.publishOn(scheduler)` method:

```
@Test
void test() {
    DirectProcessor<Object> processor = DirectProcessor.create();
    Flux<Object> flux = processor.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel());
    Runnable r = mock(Runnable.class);
    flux.subscribe(next -> {throw new RuntimeException("eee");});
    flux.subscribe(next -> r.run());

    processor.onNext(""); // onNext no longer throws an exception

    verify(r, timeout(1000)).run();
}
```